# Server side programming language to use for Gradebook system

Tags: web-development

I have a project that will develop a gradebook system like schoology.com. May I ask what server side programming language should I use for that system. Python/Django? Ruby/Ruby on Rails? or Java/Spring MVC?

Thanks for the answer.. :)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Personally, I would recommend ruby on rails, but I know a lot of people here who prefer django or something else. It's really all opinion. Which is why questions like this are considered off-topic. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having used Java web frameworks as well as ASP.NET MVC and Ruby on Rails, I can say without a doubt that I by far prefer Rails for web development. I have not used Django on a project, but hear good things about it.

As far a jobs go, I did a search on Dice.com I got back these results:

web framework-wise
spring mvc jobs in california
1 - 30 of 1093 positions

ruby on rails jobs in california
1 - 30 of 666 positions

django jobs in california
1 - 30 of 108 positions

language-wise

java jobs in california  Create Job Alert
1 - 30 of 3138 positions

python jobs in california  Create Job Alert
1 - 30 of 1917 positions

ruby jobs in california  Create Job Alert
1 - 30 of 645 positions

Java has a huge market share, like .net, through the enterprise space. I like Ruby and the Rails web framework because they are both really fun to work with. After 20 years of programming, I was getting burned out on Java, C# and static languages. I picked Ruby over Python, because I liked the syntax and libraries, but Python is growing at a faster rate and is used at companies like Google.

One of the great things about Rails is that there is so many good educational sources to get you going early on. Here are a few:

Great tutorials on many aspect of Rails
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/

This one will embed good habits from the start
https://www.railstutorial.org/book

And then there ate the free 2 part UC Berkeley course on rails development
Part 1
https://www.edx.org/course/agile-development-using-ruby-rails-uc-berkeleyx-cs169-1x

Part 2
https://www.edx.org/course/agile-development-using-ruby-rails-uc-berkeleyx-cs169-2x

So I guess it depends on what your values are. If you value maximum enjoyment while programming, go rails. Good Luck!